# Decimal pipe not working on page load

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I was trying to create a `input[number]` field which would act as an input time field.

I am using Decimal pipe (`number:'2.0-0'`) and some javascript (`if(parseInt(this.value,10)>23)this.value=23;`) to format the input number into time format.

The input functionality works fine. When I input numbers, they are transformed to time format.

For e.g.,

```
0 -> 00
9 -> 09
99 -> 23 // For hour field
99 -> 59 // For minute field
```

My problem is that the saved data on page load is not formatting the numbers. i.e. `9` stays as `9` instead of `09` on page load.

The section of code is given below.

```
<div class="col-md-2" style="padding-right: 0px">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="HH" [(ngModel)]="item.startHour"
           onchange="if(parseInt(this.value,10)>23)this.value=23;"
           name="startHour" value="{{item.startHour | number:'2.0-0'}}" [disabled]="readOnly"
           min="0" max="23" [required]="true"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2" style="padding-left: 0px">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="MM" [(ngModel)]="item.startMinute"
           onchange="if(parseInt(this.value,10)>59)this.value=59;"
           name="startMinute" value="{{item.startMinute | number:'2.0-0'}}" [disabled]="readOnly"
           min="0" max="59" [required]="true"/>
</div>
```

I am using Angular v5 in my application. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using the `ngModel` directive. `NgModel` controls the value of the input, so the expression set in the `value` attribute has no effect, as it is overriden by `NgModel`.

You should validate the data in the code of your component, including any coercion.

For example, you could make a getter/setter:

```
get minutes(): number {
    return this.item.startMinute;
}

set minutes(value: number) {
    item.startMinute = Math.max(value, 59);
}
```

This way, if by some circumstance the user inserts bad data, it it coerced to a valid value.

Now, in youf component, you bind `ngModel` to `minutes` instead of `item.startMinute`. The same can be done for the hour.

Comment: or you know, you could remove the `value` attribute, since it's useless.